# Return random value from list tuple

Tags: python

How can I return a random key value from this list tuple? I'm only concerned with returning 'r', 'p', or 's' from moves.

```
# Snippet

moves = [('r', "rock"), ('p', "paper"), ('s', "scissors")]

view_all(moves):
    print "Player moves:"
    for move in moves:
        print " => ".join((move[0], move[1]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

```
>>> import random
>>> moves = [('r', "rock"), ('p', "paper"), ('s', "scissors")]
>>> random.choice(moves)
('s', 'scissors')
```

If only the first value of the tuple is wanted:

```
random.choice(moves)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the doc link, I wasn't quite sure how to use choice. Saved me few headaches!

Comment: Glad to see it does some help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice).

```
>>> import random
>>> moves = [('r', "rock"), ('p', "paper"), ('s', "scissors")]
>>> print random.choice(moves)[0] 
's'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
moves = [('r', "rock"), ('p', "paper"), ('s', "scissors")]
move_keys = [ x[0] for x in moves ]

print random.choice(move_keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [random](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module.

`random.choice(A)` or `A[random.randint(0,len(A)-1)]`